# How to set a default date value in a inputView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I would like to set a default date value in inputView.
I have:

```
func createDatePickerDgeb1() {

    datePickergeb.datePickerMode = .date

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedgeb1))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolbar.setItems([spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)
    gebdatum.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    gebdatum.inputView = datePickergeb

}
```

The picker view shows me current date. Is possible that I can show for example the "01.01.1960" as a default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create date components
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 1960
dateComponents.month = 1
dateComponents.day = 1

// Create date from components
let userCalendar = Calendar.current // user calendar
let date = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)

// Set datePicker date
datePickergeb.setDate(date, animated: false)
```